# How to delete a specific file in an unknown directory from RAR files?

Tags: batch-file, rar

I need to delete `patata.pat` files from about 2000 *.rar files, with most of them being inside of `\unknown folder\patata\` or `\patata\` folders in those `rar` files, but could be in even deeper directories.

I've tried with no luck

```
for %%f in (*.rar) do "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\RAR.exe" d "%%f" patata.pat
```

and

```
for %%f in (*.rar) do "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\RAR.exe" d "%%f" %~dp0\patata\patata.pat
```

I guessed that the last wouldn't work.

How to delete a specific file in an unknown directory from RAR files?

Answer (score 0):

This task can be done with a batch file with the following single command line:

```
@for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*.rar" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do @"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" d -idcd "%~dp0%%I" "patata.pat" "*\patata.pat"
```

This command line works even on FAT16, FAT32 and exFAT drives without processing a *.rar file more than once.

It would be also possible to use the following command line in the batch file on execution on an NTFS partition.

```
@for %%I in ("%~dp0*.rar") do @"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" d -idcd "%%I" "patata.pat" "*\patata.pat"
```

This command line processing all *.rar files in directory of the batch file does not work correct on FAT16, FAT32 and exFAT drives because of the list of directory entries and the order of the *.rar directory entries changes on each execution of `Rar.exe` in case of a RAR file is modified because of deleting `patata.pat` from root of the archive or any directory inside the archive or the entire RAR file if not containing anything else than `patata.pat`. So RAR files are processed more than once and some RAR files could be skipped by mistake on using this command line on drives with FAT16, FAT32 or exFAT file system.

The difference is that the first command line results in executing by **FOR** in background with `%ComSpec% /c` with the **DIR** command line appended as additional arguments one more command process which executes the **DIR** command to output all RAR file names with just file name and file extension to **STDOUT** of the background command process. This output is captured by **FOR** and next processed line by line. So the changes on the directory entries list caused by `Rar.exe` do not matter because of a list of file names in memory is processed by **FOR** instead of the list of directory entries changing during the loop iterations.

The trick is to specify `patata.pat` once without any path to delete this file in root of a RAR file and once more with `*\patata.pat` to delete it from RAR file with any path stored in the RAR file. `*\` for any path is something special explained in `Rar.txt` which is the manual of *WinRAR* console version `Rar.exe`.

The RAR command `d` to delete a directory or file from a RAR file and the switch `-idcd` to suppress the copyright and `Done` messages are documented also in text file `Rar.txt`.

The directory path of the batch file referenced with `%~dp0` always expands to a string ending with `\`. For that reason `%~dp0` should be never concatenated with an additional backslash with a folder or file name as this results in having finally on execution two backslashes in series and Windows kernel must remove the additional backslash before passing the full qualified file/folder name to the file system.